# Pandas executemany nulling out columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, db2-400

I am using the pandas executemany function to load data into a DB2 database. I am having the following issue: If I insert one record with no NULLs, everything works fine; if I enter multiple records, but one has NULLs in some of the fields, it messes up all the records being inserted. The below illustrates what happens:

[image]

Edit: Some additional research, it appears the problem for one of these fields is that Pandas can't handle null integers very well. It looks like I am getting some sort of overflow when it tries to cast a null float to int; when I do explicit cast I get these same values. Is there any way to use the executemany function with null integers?

Edit2: I've tried playing around with the Int64 extension as some answers reference, but still had no luck since it still puts the type as float:

[image]

Comment: There are no "null" ints in python or numpy in general. np.nan is a float. You can have object columns which will allows mixed types (int and None/np.nan) for example

Comment: Is there no way to have pandas pass a null during the insert statements (in executemany) instead of casting a float on the fly (or whatever is happening), which seems to be having very weird results?

Comment: Yes, do that if you can. *You* need to perform the op though. DB2 is weird, non-standard etc. They should have an API somewhere that might do this for you.